# How does the HTC Sensation know it's in a dock?

Tags: docking-station, htc-sensation

I like hacking stuff together and my next project I'd like to make my own dock for my HTC Sensation. It's a fairly simple project, but the bit I can't work out is how the Sensation knows it's in a dock and launch it's dock app.

I've seen other phones that use magnets or switches, but how does the HTC Sensation do it?

Comment: On HTC phones I think it often involves connecting pin 4 (ID) on the dock's USB plug to pin 5 (ground) with a resistor, but I'm not sure if that's how it works for the Sensation. There's a bit of discussion on XDA but there's not a lot of definitive information: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1232229